# Groovy : unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I am getting "unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet" error while trying to use Soap UI 5.5 free version and poi bin files version 4.1.1.
I have below jar files in my Soap UI directory/bin/ext

- curvesapi-1.06
- ooxml-schemas-1.4
- ooxml-security-1.1
- poi-4.1.1
- poi-contrib-3.6-20091214
- poi-examples-4.1.1
- poi-excelant-4.1.1
- poi-ooxml-4.1.1
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.1
- poi-scratchpad-4.1.1
- xmlbeans-3.1.0

Please help I want to read xlsx file data.
Below is my code

```
    import java.io.File
    import java.io.IOException
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    import java.util.Iterator
    import java.*
    import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
    import groovy.*
    import groovy.json.*
    import groovy.json.JsonOutput
    import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
    import javax.xml.parsers.*
    import com.jayway.jsonpath.*
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row


    log.info("start")


    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C://Unique.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file)
    XSSFSheet readsheet1 = workbook1.getSheet("Data")
    Iterator rows = readsheet1.rowIterator();
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I get an error while trying to import the XSSF Sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I simulated your error. What you have is dependency problems. If you look at the **next line** of the stack trace that you got, it shows you what is wrong. It looks like this:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: 
startup failed: General error during class generation: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook 
due to missing dependency org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
```

See the **missing dependency** part? It is probably bundled in the POI zip under /lib. Add it.

If it is not bundled with the POI you downloaded, you can search for org/apache/commons/collections4 on https://mvnrepository.com you will find a place where you can [download](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.4) the jar.

Add it to your [Soap UI directory]/bin/ext, then restart SoapUI (it has to reload the libraries) and try again. I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
```

Now you know what to do, until all your missing dependency / NoClassDefFoundError are resolved. It's tedious, but once it's done it should work. Also teach yourself to read stack traces, they can give you a lot of information.

This is the reason for dependency management tools like Maven, they do it all for you in the background, which is not really possible when using plain SoapUI.

Comment: The binary download for Apache POI does include all the required dependencies, and they're also [listed on the website](http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components)